# Deleted Linux partitions on dual-boot computer but GRUB screen appears

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, grub, linux-mint, uefi

I had Linux installation alongside Windows 10 on my dual booted laptop. I wanted to remove the Linux partition so I followed guides online so I deleted the 3 partitions associated with my Linux Mint installation... (I'm assuming I deleted every one...)

[Click here for Disk management screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmOg8.png)

I then inserted my Windows recovery disk and then entered on the terminal the following commands, `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`, `bootrec.exe /fixboot` and `bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd`. I then rebooted and got a black screen saying `"Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported."`, along with some more text.

So I then did some more digging around on the web and tried the following commands:

`bootsect /nt60 C:
bootsect /nt60 sys
bootsect /nt60 all
bootsect /nt60 sys /mbr`

but got the following as output on the terminal:

`Bootcode is only updated on MBR partitioned disks. A different partitioning scheme is used on this disk'. Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes.`

Is this message normal?

So I then did more googling and then booted from my Linux installation USB and installed then ran the **boot-repair** program. This also didn't work and the grub screen still appeared!

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem that the grub screen (`Minimal BASH-like line editing`..) still appears?

Comment: I seemed to have fixed it with the Easy BCD tool? I did an Automatic Repair within it and my laptop booted straight into Windows

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a UEFI based install

First, enter your computer's SETUP (typically by pressing delete or F2 while the computer is booting). Within setup you usually have the option to rearrange or remove boot options.

Once the boot option for grub has been removed, you can delete Grub's files from the EFI system partition, (you can assign it a drive letter either in disk management or diskpart)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I seemed to have fixed it with the Easy BCD tool? I did an Automatic Repair within it and my laptop booted straight into Windows. I assume it's now fixed?